# How to display parts of value from database with different font size in SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

One of my columns has a value that looks like this -> "$5.95 (Park costs)"

and I need to display the value in column in SSRS report like this:

```
$5.95
(Park costs)
```

but font size of "(Park costs)" must be **smaller** than the price.

Is something like that even possible? To somehow make text that does not contain a number, dot or dollar sign smaller?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. You'll need to split up each component of the text column and then place each half in a placeholder. You can then format each placeholder individually.

This solution assumes that your column always contains a "(". If not you should be able to modify it to suit.

I Generated some test data and and placed it in a normal table (tablix) control.

I then added some new columns for testing that each part was working as expected.

The expression for "Cost" column is

```
=TRIM(LEFT(Fields!MyColumn.Value,InStr(Fields!MyColumn.Value, "(") -1))
```

The expression for the "Caption" column is

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(Fields!MyColumn.Value, LEN(Fields!MyColumn.Value) - InStr(Fields!MyColumn.Value, "(") + 1))
```

Once this was working OK I added the "Final Column".

To add a placeholder, click inside the textbox so the cursor appears then right-click and choose "Create Placeholder"

[image]

I added two placeholders with a space between then and set the values to the expressions above respectively. I then right clicked the placeholders chose "Placeholder Properties" and formatted each individually.

The final output looks like this. (I left the test columns in for clarity)

[image]